# Static url is not working whenever I am trying to use slug to show a blog details

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-staticfiles

My other pages static url is working great but when ever I am trying to show a blog details, my static url is changing

its showing   http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/this-is-testing-number-1/media/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
instead of  http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

my blog app views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Blog
# Create your views here.



def details(request, slug):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {
        'blog':blog
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_details.html', context)
```

my blog app urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from froala_editor import views
from .views import *



urlpatterns = [
    path('froala_editor/',include('froala_editor.urls')),
    path('<slug>/', details, name='details')
]
```

my blog details.html

```
    <!-- CSS
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/assets/css/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/assets/css/simple-scrollbar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/assets/css/fontawesome.all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="media/assets/css/style.css" />

    <script src="media/assets/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

my static settings

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIR = {
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR , "public/static")
}

MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/
```

my main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

how to fix this.

I was expecting my staic url  like this down below

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css**

but i was gettting like this down below when i am trying to show a blog details using slug.

**http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/this-is-testing-number-1/media/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css**

Comment: Use `"/media/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"`, with a slash in front.

Comment: I have tried it. But the result is same